# Is it possible to load Windows Calculator in a particular view?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, calculator

In Windows 7, Calculator has four different views:

- Standard
- Scientific
- Programmer
- Statistics

When I load the calculator, I know whether I want to do hex arithmatic/conversion (Programmer view) or standard maths (Standard/Scientific).  Is it possible to load the calculator into a specified view from the command line, an AutoHotkey macro or some other mechanism?

Comment: `alt-1`, `alt-2`, etc can be used to toggle the view between the various modes, so that can likely be easily scripted into AutoHotkey (which sounds better than modifying the registry on each start).  Alternatively, just learning and using the shortcuts is probably the easiest route.

Answer (score 2):

[According to this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/043e483d-b8f6-408e-a999-dadd9ae7454d/calcexe-command-line-arguments?forum=vbgeneral) The setting is in the Registry, under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Calc`, the value-name is `Layout` and has these possible values:

- 0 - Scientific
- 1 - Standard
- 2 - Programmer
- 3 - Statistical

I don't know Autohotkey myself, but you'll need to write a simple script that sets this registry value before launching the new `calc.exe` process.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotkey allows waiting until a window is active and can send key combinations, so the following will configure Windows Key+C to open Calculator in the Standard view, Windows Key+S for Scientific view, Windows Key+P for Programmer view and Windows Key+T for Statistics view.

```
#c:: ; Standard view
Run Calc
WinWaitActive Calculator
SendInput !1
Return

#s:: ; Scientific view
Run Calc
WinWaitActive Calculator
SendInput !2
Return

#p:: ; Programmer View
Run Calc
WinWaitActive Calculator
SendInput !3
Return

#t:: ; Statistics view
Run Calc
WinWaitActive Calculator
SendInput !4
Return
```